# How do I give Serial Numbers query using dual table and without declaring variable in SQL

Tags: sql

How do I give serial numbers query using dual table and without declaring a variable in SQL?

Comment: Tag dbms used, since the answer may depend on it.

Comment: Well, 'dual table' suggests Oracle, but I really don't understand what the question is. I think Aniket needs to expand it a bit.

Comment: what do you mean by *Serial Numbers* ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned the db name, I am taking a guess here. In Oracle, you can use `level` to get a sequence. Example for generating `1` to `100`, you can use

```
select level from dual 
connect by level<=100;
```

.

However, dual table is used in `DB2` also.

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the DB name my Db is Oracle. Also to expand the problem, I have situation where I want to have serial numbers to be populate using query while I am creating XML.

Comment: Hi. The answer was for original question on `serial number` using `dual` table. If this solution worked for that specific thing, then please accept the answer (by clicking on tick symbol on left of this answer) so it could be closed.

Comment: For your new requirement, please ask a new question mentioning the specific thing you are trying to achieve and with sample data and expected output.